# Не работают кнопки в PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qt-designer

Пишу калькулятор на *Python* с помощью *PyQt5*. Дизайн делаю в Qt Designer.

Суть в том, что когда я вставляю в `stylesheet` кнопки свойство `border-radius` у меня перестает работать кнопка. Как только я его убираю - она работает, но превращается в квадратную, что мне совершенно не нужно.

Как оставить кнопку круглой и заставить ее работать? Пробовал собирать из `.ui` в `.py` - там тоже ничего не работает, соответственно.

Снизу **.ui** файл

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>321</width>
    <height>481</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="font">
   <font>
    <family>SF Pro Display</family>
   </font>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="central_widget_grid">
   <property name="font">
    <font>
     <pointsize>8</pointsize>
    </font>
   </property>
   <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
    <property name="leftMargin">
     <number>30</number>
    </property>
    <property name="topMargin">
     <number>50</number>
    </property>
    <property name="rightMargin">
     <number>30</number>
    </property>
    <property name="bottomMargin">
     <number>0</number>
    </property>
    <property name="horizontalSpacing">
     <number>7</number>
    </property>
    <item row="1" column="0">
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="btn_clear_display">
      <property name="sizePolicy">
       <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Preferred">
        <horstretch>0</horstretch>
        <verstretch>0</verstretch>
       </sizepolicy>
      </property>
      <property name="font">
       <font>
        <pointsize>12</pointsize>
       </font>
      </property>
      <property name="styleSheet">
       <string notr="true">border-radius: 30px;
background-color:rgb(166,166,166);
color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
;</string>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>C</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="3" column="2">
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="btn_six">
      <property name="sizePolicy">
       <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Preferred">
        <horstretch>0</horstretch>
        <verstretch>0</verstretch>
       </sizepolicy>
      </property>
      <property name="font">
       <font>
        <pointsize>12</pointsize>
       </font>
      </property>
      <property name="styleSheet">
       <string notr="true">  border-radius: 30px;
background-color: rgb(229, 229, 234);
color: rgb(0, 0, 0);</string>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>6</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="4" column="1">
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="btn_two">
      <property name="sizePolicy">
       <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Preferred">
        <horstretch>0</horstretch>
        <verstretch>0</verstretch>
       </sizepolicy>
      </property>
      <property name="font">
       <font>
        <pointsize>12</pointsize>
       </font>
      </property>
      <property name="styleSheet">
       <string notr="true">  border-radius: 30px;
background-color: rgb(229, 229, 234);
color: rgb(0, 0, 0);</string>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>2</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="5" column="2">
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="btn_equally">
      <property name="sizePolicy">
       <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Preferred">
        <horstretch>0</horstretch>
        <verstretch>0</verstretch>
       </sizepolicy>
      </property>
      <property name="font">
       <font>
        <pointsize>12</pointsize>
       </font>
      </property>
      <property name="styleSheet">
       <string notr="true">  border-radius: 30px;
background-color: rgb(229, 229, 234);
color: rgb(0, 0, 0);</string>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>=</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="3" column="0">
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="btn_four">
      <property name="sizePolicy">
       <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Preferred">
        <horstretch>0</horstretch>
        <verstretch>0</verstretch>
       </sizepolicy>
      </property>
      <property name="font">
       <font>
        <pointsize>12</pointsize>
       </font>
      </property>
      <property name="styleSheet">
       <string notr="true">  border-radius: 30px;
background-color: rgb(229, 229, 234);
color: rgb(0, 0, 0);</string>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>4</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="1" column="3">
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="btn_undo_action">
      <property name="sizePolicy">
       <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Preferred">
        <horstretch>0</horstretch>
        <verstretch>0</verstretch>
       </sizepolicy>
      </property>
      <property name="font">
       <font>
        <pointsize>12</pointsize>
       </font>
      </property>
      <property name="styleSheet">
       <string notr="true">border-radius: 30px;
background-color: rgb(26,115,233);
color: rgb(255, 255, 255);</string>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>←</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="1" column="2">
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="btn_mod">
      <property name="sizePolicy">
       <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Preferred">
        <horstretch>0</horstretch>
        <verstretch>0</verstretch>
       </sizepolicy>
      </property>
      <property name="font">
       <font>
        <pointsize>12</pointsize>
       </font>
      </property>
      <property name="styleSheet">
       <string notr="true">border-radius: 30px;
background-color:rgb(166,166,166);
color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
;</string>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>%</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="1" column="1">
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="btn_int_div">
      <property name="sizePolicy">
       <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Preferred">
        <horstretch>0</horstretch>
        <verstretch>0</verstretch>
       </sizepolicy>
      </property>
      <property name="font">
       <font>
        <pointsize>12</pointsize>
       </font>
      </property>
      <property name="styleSheet">
       <string notr="true">border-radius: 30px;
background-color:rgb(166,166,166);
color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
;</string>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>//</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="0" column="0" colspan="4">
     <widget class="QLabel" name="label_calculation_result">
      <property name="sizePolicy">
       <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Preferred">
        <horstretch>0</horstretch>
        <verstretch>0</verstretch>
       </sizepolicy>
      </property>
      <property name="maximumSize">
       <size>
        <width>16777215</width>
        <height>63</height>
       </size>
      </property>
      <property name="font">
       <font>
        <pointsize>32</pointsize>
        <weight>75</weight>
        <bold>true</bold>
       </font>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>0</string>
      </property>
      <property name="alignment">
       <set>Qt::AlignBottom|Qt::AlignRight|Qt::AlignTrailing</set>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="3" column="1">
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="btn_five">
      <property name="sizePolicy">
       <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Preferred">
        <horstretch>0</horstretch>
        <verstretch>0</verstretch>
       </sizepolicy>
      </property>
      <property name="font">
       <font>
        <pointsize>12</pointsize>
       </font>
      </property>
      <property name="styleSheet">
       <string notr="true">  border-radius: 30px;
background-color: rgb(229, 229, 234);
color: rgb(0, 0, 0);</string>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>5</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="2" column="1">
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="btn_eight">
      <property name="sizePolicy">
       <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Preferred">
        <horstretch>0</horstretch>
        <verstretch>0</verstretch>
       </sizepolicy>
      </property>
      <property name="font">
       <font>
        <pointsize>12</pointsize>
       </font>
      </property>
      <property name="styleSheet">
       <string notr="true">  border-radius: 30px;
background-color: rgb(229, 229, 234);
color: rgb(0, 0, 0);</string>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>8</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="2" column="0">
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="btn_seven">
      <property name="sizePolicy">
       <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Preferred">
        <horstretch>0</horstretch>
        <verstretch>0</verstretch>
       </sizepolicy>
      </property>
      <property name="font">
       <font>
        <pointsize>12</pointsize>
       </font>
      </property>
      <property name="styleSheet">
       <string notr="true">  border-radius: 30px;
background-color: rgb(229, 229, 234);
color: rgb(0, 0, 0);</string>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>7</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="2" column="3">
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="btn_division">
      <property name="sizePolicy">
       <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Preferred">
        <horstretch>0</horstretch>
        <verstretch>0</verstretch>
       </sizepolicy>
      </property>
      <property name="font">
       <font>
        <pointsize>12</pointsize>
       </font>
      </property>
      <property name="styleSheet">
       <string notr="true">border-radius: 30px;
background-color: rgb(26,115,233);
color: rgb(255, 255, 255);</string>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>÷</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="2" column="2">
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="btn_nine">
      <property name="sizePolicy">
       <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Preferred">
        <horstretch>0</horstretch>
        <verstretch>0</verstretch>
       </sizepolicy>
      </property>
      <property name="font">
       <font>
        <pointsize>12</pointsize>
       </font>
      </property>
      <property name="styleSheet">
       <string notr="true">  border-radius: 30px;
background-color: rgb(229, 229, 234);
color: rgb(0, 0, 0);</string>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>9</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="3" column="3">
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="btn_multiplication">
      <property name="sizePolicy">
       <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Preferred">
        <horstretch>0</horstretch>
        <verstretch>0</verstretch>
       </sizepolicy>
      </property>
      <property name="font">
       <font>
        <pointsize>12</pointsize>
       </font>
      </property>
      <property name="styleSheet">
       <string notr="true">border-radius: 30px;
background-color: rgb(26,115,233);
color: rgb(255, 255, 255);</string>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>×</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="4" column="3">
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="btn_minus">
      <property name="sizePolicy">
       <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Preferred">
        <horstretch>0</horstretch>
        <verstretch>0</verstretch>
       </sizepolicy>
      </property>
      <property name="font">
       <font>
        <pointsize>12</pointsize>
       </font>
      </property>
      <property name="styleSheet">
       <string notr="true">border-radius: 30px;
background-color: rgb(26,115,233);
color: rgb(255, 255, 255);</string>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>-</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="4" column="0">
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="btn_one">
      <property name="sizePolicy">
       <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Preferred">
        <horstretch>0</horstretch>
        <verstretch>0</verstretch>
       </sizepolicy>
      </property>
      <property name="font">
       <font>
        <pointsize>12</pointsize>
       </font>
      </property>
      <property name="styleSheet">
       <string notr="true">  border-radius: 30px;
background-color: rgb(229, 229, 234);
color: rgb(0, 0, 0);</string>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>1</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="4" column="2">
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="btn_three">
      <property name="sizePolicy">
       <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Preferred">
        <horstretch>0</horstretch>
        <verstretch>0</verstretch>
       </sizepolicy>
      </property>
      <property name="font">
       <font>
        <pointsize>12</pointsize>
       </font>
      </property>
      <property name="styleSheet">
       <string notr="true">  border-radius: 30px;
background-color: rgb(229, 229, 234);
color: rgb(0, 0, 0);</string>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>3</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="5" column="0">
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="btn_zero">
      <property name="sizePolicy">
       <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Preferred">
        <horstretch>0</horstretch>
        <verstretch>0</verstretch>
       </sizepolicy>
      </property>
      <property name="font">
       <font>
        <pointsize>12</pointsize>
       </font>
      </property>
      <property name="styleSheet">
       <string notr="true">  border-radius: 30px;
background-color: rgb(229, 229, 234);
color: rgb(0, 0, 0);</string>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>0</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="5" column="1">
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="btn_decimal_separator">
      <property name="sizePolicy">
       <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Preferred">
        <horstretch>0</horstretch>
        <verstretch>0</verstretch>
       </sizepolicy>
      </property>
      <property name="font">
       <font>
        <pointsize>12</pointsize>
       </font>
      </property>
      <property name="styleSheet">
       <string notr="true">  border-radius: 30px;
background-color: rgb(229, 229, 234);
color: rgb(0, 0, 0);</string>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>,</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="5" column="3">
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="btn_plus">
      <property name="sizePolicy">
       <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Preferred">
        <horstretch>0</horstretch>
        <verstretch>0</verstretch>
       </sizepolicy>
      </property>
      <property name="font">
       <font>
        <pointsize>12</pointsize>
       </font>
      </property>
      <property name="styleSheet">
       <string notr="true">border-radius: 30px;
background-color: rgb(26,115,233);
color: rgb(255, 255, 255);</string>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>+</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>321</width>
     <height>26</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]  и модуль  `.ui`

Comment: прикрепил ui файл, а насчет примера - все работает так, как я и описал

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**НИКОГДА НЕ ИЗМЕНЯЙТЕ код, сгенерированный Qt Designer**. Создайте другой класс,
который наследуется от соответствующего виджета, и используйте созданный класс для его заполнения.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(321, 481)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("SF Pro Display")
        MainWindow.setFont(font)
        self.central_widget_grid = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(8)
        self.central_widget_grid.setFont(font)
        self.central_widget_grid.setObjectName("central_widget_grid")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.central_widget_grid)
        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(30, 50, 30, 0)
        self.gridLayout.setHorizontalSpacing(7)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.btn_clear_display = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.central_widget_grid)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.btn_clear_display.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.btn_clear_display.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.btn_clear_display.setFont(font)
        self.btn_clear_display.setStyleSheet("border-radius: 30px;\n"
"background-color:rgb(166,166,166);\n"
"color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
";")
        self.btn_clear_display.setObjectName("btn_clear_display")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.btn_clear_display, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.btn_six = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.central_widget_grid)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.btn_six.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.btn_six.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.btn_six.setFont(font)
        self.btn_six.setStyleSheet("  border-radius: 30px;\n"
"background-color: rgb(229, 229, 234);\n"
"color: rgb(0, 0, 0);")
        self.btn_six.setObjectName("btn_six")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.btn_six, 3, 2, 1, 1)
        self.btn_two = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.central_widget_grid)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.btn_two.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.btn_two.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.btn_two.setFont(font)
        self.btn_two.setStyleSheet("  border-radius: 30px;\n"
"background-color: rgb(229, 229, 234);\n"
"color: rgb(0, 0, 0);")
        self.btn_two.setObjectName("btn_two")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.btn_two, 4, 1, 1, 1)
        self.btn_equally = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.central_widget_grid)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.btn_equally.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.btn_equally.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.btn_equally.setFont(font)
        self.btn_equally.setStyleSheet("  border-radius: 30px;\n"
"background-color: rgb(229, 229, 234);\n"
"color: rgb(0, 0, 0);")
        self.btn_equally.setObjectName("btn_equally")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.btn_equally, 5, 2, 1, 1)
        self.btn_four = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.central_widget_grid)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.btn_four.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.btn_four.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.btn_four.setFont(font)
        self.btn_four.setStyleSheet("  border-radius: 30px;\n"
"background-color: rgb(229, 229, 234);\n"
"color: rgb(0, 0, 0);")
        self.btn_four.setObjectName("btn_four")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.btn_four, 3, 0, 1, 1)
        self.btn_undo_action = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.central_widget_grid)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.btn_undo_action.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.btn_undo_action.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.btn_undo_action.setFont(font)
        self.btn_undo_action.setStyleSheet("border-radius: 30px;\n"
"background-color: rgb(26,115,233);\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.btn_undo_action.setObjectName("btn_undo_action")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.btn_undo_action, 1, 3, 1, 1)
        self.btn_mod = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.central_widget_grid)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.btn_mod.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.btn_mod.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.btn_mod.setFont(font)
        self.btn_mod.setStyleSheet("border-radius: 30px;\n"
"background-color:rgb(166,166,166);\n"
"color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
";")
        self.btn_mod.setObjectName("btn_mod")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.btn_mod, 1, 2, 1, 1)
        self.btn_int_div = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.central_widget_grid)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.btn_int_div.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.btn_int_div.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.btn_int_div.setFont(font)
        self.btn_int_div.setStyleSheet("border-radius: 30px;\n"
"background-color:rgb(166,166,166);\n"
"color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
";")
        self.btn_int_div.setObjectName("btn_int_div")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.btn_int_div, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.label_calculation_result = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.central_widget_grid)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.label_calculation_result.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.label_calculation_result.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.label_calculation_result.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 63))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(32)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_calculation_result.setFont(font)
        self.label_calculation_result.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom|QtCore.Qt.AlignRight|QtCore.Qt.AlignTrailing)
        self.label_calculation_result.setObjectName("label_calculation_result")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_calculation_result, 0, 0, 1, 4)
        self.btn_five = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.central_widget_grid)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.btn_five.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.btn_five.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.btn_five.setFont(font)
        self.btn_five.setStyleSheet("  border-radius: 30px;\n"
"background-color: rgb(229, 229, 234);\n"
"color: rgb(0, 0, 0);")
        self.btn_five.setObjectName("btn_five")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.btn_five, 3, 1, 1, 1)
        self.btn_eight = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.central_widget_grid)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.btn_eight.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.btn_eight.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.btn_eight.setFont(font)
        self.btn_eight.setStyleSheet("  border-radius: 30px;\n"
"background-color: rgb(229, 229, 234);\n"
"color: rgb(0, 0, 0);")
        self.btn_eight.setObjectName("btn_eight")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.btn_eight, 2, 1, 1, 1)
        self.btn_seven = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.central_widget_grid)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.btn_seven.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.btn_seven.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.btn_seven.setFont(font)
        self.btn_seven.setStyleSheet("  border-radius: 30px;\n"
"background-color: rgb(229, 229, 234);\n"
"color: rgb(0, 0, 0);")
        self.btn_seven.setObjectName("btn_seven")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.btn_seven, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.btn_division = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.central_widget_grid)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.btn_division.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.btn_division.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.btn_division.setFont(font)
        self.btn_division.setStyleSheet("border-radius: 30px;\n"
"background-color: rgb(26,115,233);\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.btn_division.setObjectName("btn_division")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.btn_division, 2, 3, 1, 1)
        self.btn_nine = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.central_widget_grid)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.btn_nine.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.btn_nine.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.btn_nine.setFont(font)
        self.btn_nine.setStyleSheet("  border-radius: 30px;\n"
"background-color: rgb(229, 229, 234);\n"
"color: rgb(0, 0, 0);")
        self.btn_nine.setObjectName("btn_nine")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.btn_nine, 2, 2, 1, 1)
        self.btn_multiplication = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.central_widget_grid)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.btn_multiplication.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.btn_multiplication.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.btn_multiplication.setFont(font)
        self.btn_multiplication.setStyleSheet("border-radius: 30px;\n"
"background-color: rgb(26,115,233);\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.btn_multiplication.setObjectName("btn_multiplication")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.btn_multiplication, 3, 3, 1, 1)
        self.btn_minus = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.central_widget_grid)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.btn_minus.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.btn_minus.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.btn_minus.setFont(font)
        self.btn_minus.setStyleSheet("border-radius: 30px;\n"
"background-color: rgb(26,115,233);\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.btn_minus.setObjectName("btn_minus")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.btn_minus, 4, 3, 1, 1)
        self.btn_one = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.central_widget_grid)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.btn_one.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.btn_one.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.btn_one.setFont(font)
        self.btn_one.setStyleSheet("  border-radius: 30px;\n"
"background-color: rgb(229, 229, 234);\n"
"color: rgb(0, 0, 0);")
        self.btn_one.setObjectName("btn_one")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.btn_one, 4, 0, 1, 1)
        self.btn_three = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.central_widget_grid)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.btn_three.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.btn_three.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.btn_three.setFont(font)
        self.btn_three.setStyleSheet("  border-radius: 30px;\n"
"background-color: rgb(229, 229, 234);\n"
"color: rgb(0, 0, 0);")
        self.btn_three.setObjectName("btn_three")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.btn_three, 4, 2, 1, 1)
        self.btn_zero = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.central_widget_grid)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.btn_zero.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.btn_zero.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.btn_zero.setFont(font)
        self.btn_zero.setStyleSheet("  border-radius: 30px;\n"
"background-color: rgb(229, 229, 234);\n"
"color: rgb(0, 0, 0);")
        self.btn_zero.setObjectName("btn_zero")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.btn_zero, 5, 0, 1, 1)
        self.btn_decimal_separator = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.central_widget_grid)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.btn_decimal_separator.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.btn_decimal_separator.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.btn_decimal_separator.setFont(font)
        self.btn_decimal_separator.setStyleSheet("  border-radius: 30px;\n"
"background-color: rgb(229, 229, 234);\n"
"color: rgb(0, 0, 0);")
        self.btn_decimal_separator.setObjectName("btn_decimal_separator")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.btn_decimal_separator, 5, 1, 1, 1)
        self.btn_plus = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.central_widget_grid)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.btn_plus.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.btn_plus.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.btn_plus.setFont(font)
        self.btn_plus.setStyleSheet("border-radius: 30px;\n"
"background-color: rgb(26,115,233);\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.btn_plus.setObjectName("btn_plus")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.btn_plus, 5, 3, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget_grid)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 321, 26))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.btn_clear_display.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "C"))
        self.btn_six.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "6"))
        self.btn_two.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "2"))
        self.btn_equally.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "="))
        self.btn_four.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "4"))
        self.btn_undo_action.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "←"))
        self.btn_mod.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "%"))
        self.btn_int_div.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "//"))
        self.label_calculation_result.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "0")) 
        self.btn_five.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "5"))
        self.btn_eight.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "8"))
        self.btn_seven.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "7"))
        self.btn_division.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "÷"))
        self.btn_nine.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "9"))
        self.btn_multiplication.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "×"))
        self.btn_minus.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "-"))
        self.btn_one.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        self.btn_three.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "3"))
        self.btn_zero.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "0"))
        self.btn_decimal_separator.setText(_translate("MainWindow", ","))
        self.btn_plus.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "+"))


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.btn_zero.clicked.connect(self.add_functions)
        self.btn_one.clicked.connect(self.add_functions)
        self.btn_two.clicked.connect(self.add_functions)
        self.btn_three.clicked.connect(self.add_functions)
        # ... и так далее

    def add_functions(self):
#            self.btn_zero.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write_number(self.btn_zero.text()))
        sender = self.sender()
        self.write_number(sender.text())

    def write_number(self, number):
        print(number)        
        
        self.label_calculation_result.setText(number)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
#    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
#    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Понял. Большое спасибо!

Comment: @CameUp пожадуйста